# How to extract consecutive elements from an array containing NaN

Tags: python, numpy

Consider following numpy array

```
x = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4, 5, np.nan])
```

I want to extract all non-NaN consecutive elements in `x` and the expected outputs is the list

```
y = [[1, 2],[3, 4, 5]]
```

Is their any method that is both elegant and faster than simple `for` loop ?

Comment: How is that converting into a nested list?

Comment: @DirtyBit did you read his question?  He's wanting it into a list of lists.

Answer (score 5):

using `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [list(map(int,g)) for k,g in groupby(x, np.isnan) if not k]
print (result)
#[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: There is an amazing shortcut for `lambda y:np.isnan(y)`, y'know ;-)

Comment: what is the shortcut for that `lambda` function ?

Comment: @JunjieChen Just recap what this particular lambda is doing: "GIven an input `y` return `np.isnan(y)`." Notice something? That is precisely what `np.isnan` does on its own. `result = [list(map(int,g)) for k,g in groupby(x, np.isnan) if not k]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np.split`:

```
np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(np.isnan(x), prepend=True))[0])[1::2]
#[array([1., 2.]), array([3., 4., 5.])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`more_itertools.consecutive_groups`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.consecutive_groups):

**Given**

```
import numpy as np

import more_itertools as mit


iterable = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 5, 6, 7, np.nan])
```

**Code**

```
[x for x in map(list, mit.consecutive_groups(iterable)) if len(x) != 1]
# [[1.0, 2.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]
```

Equivalently:

```
list(filter(lambda x: len(x) != 1, map(list, mit.consecutive_groups(iterable))))
# [[1.0, 2.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0]]
```

*Note: [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/) is a third-party library.  Install via `> pip install more_itertools`.*